# O período está correto quanto à regência verbal?

Tags: crase, regência-verbal

Reescrevendo-se o segmento frasal:

> ... incitá-los a reagir e a enfrentar o desconforto, ...

De acordo com a regência e o acento indicativo da crase, tem-se:

> ... incitá-los **à** reação e **ao** enfrentamento do desconforto, ...

Está correto?

- O pronome oblíquo "-los" é o objeto direto;
- O "à" é craseado pela união da preposição + artigo(exigida pela regência do verbo incitar);
- O "ao" é fruto da união da preposição + artigo(exigida pela regência do verbo incitar).

E o verbo incitar nesse contexto é bitransitivo?

> "... incitá-los à reação e ao enfrentamento do desconforto, ..."

A frase foi retirada do livro "1500 questões comentadas de português"

Comment: Se foi retirado do livro, qual é o problema?

Comment: @Lambie o comentário do livro não ajuda em nada, a unica parte do livro que eu retirei foi a parte destacada, as vezes os autores erram

Comment: Claro, a crase se usa só se houver a (preposição) + palavra no feminino. Então incitar ***a*** a reação=à reação, e se for a+ o, vira ao, ou seja, ao enfrentamento. Não creo que sería possível outra coisa, né? :)

Answer (score 1):

incitar

```
1.
transitivo direto e bitransitivo
estimular (alguém) [a]; instigar, encorajar.
"a curiosidade incitava-o (a constantes buscas)"
2.
transitivo direto e pronominal
causar ou ter uma reação; estimular(-se), excitar(-se).
"incitar os sentimentos"
```

Assim, o uso do verbo incitar no exemplo dado está correto.

```
"... incitá-los à reação e ao enfrentamento do desconforto, ..."
```

O uso aqui é bitransitivo, inicitar **OS** elementos **A** reagir e **A** enfrentar.
São duas preposições. Caso se substitua o verbo "reagir" e "enfrentar" pelos substantivos  precedidos de artigos definidos "a reação", ou "o enfrentamento" então este A será craseado, já que será a junção da preposição "a" com o artigo "a", e o artigo "o" será substituido por AO, união da preposição A com o artigo definido O:

```
"...incitá-los a reagir e a enfrentar o desconforto, ..."
```

torna-se:

```
"...incitálos à reação e ao enfrentamento do desconforto, ..."
```

Comment: Zuabros, as definições que dás logo ao princípio parecem ver dum dicionário ou coisa assim. Seria melhor indicares a fonte.